# Jquery slideToggle function calling div-tag from code behind

Tags: javascript, jquery

Iam trying to do slidetoggel function(jquery) and calling the div tag from code behind. i have done that before but now its not working. All other scripts src working.

```
Code behind

     string boxen = "<div class=\"alter-Wrp\">/div>";
        litAlert.Text += String.Format(boxen);

 asp.page    
         <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $("#btn-VG").click(function () {
                        $(".alert-Wrp").slideToggle();
                    });
                }); </script>

         <button id="btn-VG">Button</button>
                <asp:Literal ID="litAlert" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your html is not proper. 
   /div>
Also what are the errors ?
Did you see it in browser's console?

try $(".alert-Wrp") in the console and see if it returns anything?
Also $("#btn-Wrp").click() in console and see what happen

Comment: It works when I put the code from jquery in an external file, but the whole page refreshes and then div tagen up again..